# How to collect data from multiple threads in the parent process with ZeroMQ while keeping the solution both as simple & as scaleable as possible?

Tags: python, multithreading, zeromq, pyzmq

The parent process launches **a few tens** of threads that receive data (up to few KB, 10 requests per second), which has to be collected in a list in the parent process. What is the recommended way to achieve this, which is efficient, asynchronous, non-blocking, and simpler to implement with least overhead?

The ZeroMQ guide recommends using a **`PAIR`** socket archetype for coordinating threads, but
 **how to scale** that with **a few hundred threads?**

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If a parent process spawns threads then all of those threads share memory and they can write directly to a common list. It's simpliest and the most efficient solution at the same time.

Comment: Threads should not share state, as [all interaction between threads happens as ZeroMQ messages](http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:all#Multithreading-with-ZeroMQ).

Comment: What? Why threads should not share state? Sharing state is the **essence** of threads, that's why they were developed in the first place. Why would you use 0MQ instead? It's a huge overkill. That only makes sense if you assume that eventually you will have to scale onto multiple processes/machines. Otherwise it's just ridiculous.

Comment: The remarks above are correct on both sides. @freakish correctly proposed a solution based on shared-resources. MK correctly commented on ZeroMQ design-philosophy principle to share nothing ( the Zero-Sharing maxim ). You just do not understand each others' point of view. Try to open your minds to the other's proposal. You both learn a bit from each other. Enjoy the day, sirs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There is no dinner for free

even if some marketing blable offers that, do not take it for granted.

Efficient means usually a complex resources handling.

Simplest to implement usually fights with overheads & efficient resources handling.

---

### Simplest?

Using sir Henry FORD's point of view, a component, that is not present in one's design simply cannot fail.

In this very sense, we strive here not to programmatically control anything beyond the simplest possible use of elementary components of an otherwise smart ZeroMQ library:

**`Scenario SIMPLEST:`**

> **Rule a)**

The **central `HQ`-unit** ( be it just a thread or a fully isolated process ) **`.bind()`**-s it's receiving port ( pre-set as a **`ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE`** behaviour-archetype ) and "subscribes" it's *topic-filter* to "everything" **`.setsockopt( ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "" )`** before it spawns the first `DAQ`-{ thread | process }, further ref'd as **`DAQ`-unit**.

> **Rule b)**

**Each `DAQ`-unit** simply **`.connect()`**-s to an already setup & ready port on the `HQ`-unit with a unit-local socket access-port, pre-set as a **`ZMQ_PUBLISH`** behaviour-archetype.

> **Rule c)**

**Any `DAQ`-unit** simply **`.send( ..., ZMQ_NOBLOCK )`**-s as needed it's local-data via a message, which is being delivered in the background by the ZeroMQ-layer to the hands of the `HQ`-unit, being there queued & available for a further processing at the `HQ`-unit's will.

> **Rule d)**

The **`HQ`-unit** regularly loops and **`.poll( 1 )`**-s for a presence of a collected message from any `DAQ`-unit + **`.recv( ZMQ_NOBLOCK )`** in case any such was present.

**That's all**
`Asynchronous`: **yes.**
`Non-blocking`: **yes.**
`Simplest`: **yes.**
`Scaleable`: **yes.** *Almost linearly, until I/O-bound
  <sub>( still some tweaking possible to handle stressed-I/O-operations )</sub>  as a bonus-point...*

Comment: What are the reasons to prefer **`PUB`** / **`SUB`** socket archetype pattern over **`PUSH`** / **`PULL`** in this scenario?

Comment: The integrated ***topic-filter***. This would require an additional code and **would consume both `HQ`**-node's and **`DAQ`**-nodes' **processing / storage resources** to achieve the almost a same level of comfort / configuration-flexibility / system-wide security against a DDoS attack in a `PUSH` / `PULL` behavioural archetype.

Comment: For the same scenario, but on a small scale, what can be good arguments for not using [built-in thread-safe queue](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html), instead of **`PUB`** / **`SUB`** sockets?

Comment: The Economy.One could have done the job within 5 minutes already, with a scale-proof architecture, or try to design another, unsure attempt to have such solution, but have uncertain economies of time & labor and a doubtfull outlook what if one node has to move to another host and have the whole circus elaborated so far useless, as thread-based process mobility is zero.

Comment: Just to add, the [ZeroMQ guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:all#toc46) comments on using **`PUB`** / **`SUB`** as: "This will correctly deliver your messages exactly as you sent them and `PUB` _does not distribute_ as `PUSH` or `DEALER` do". 

With only [one caveat](http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:all#toc46) that "you need to configure the subscriber with an empty subscription, _which is annoying_", but this is a non-issue in this scenario.